# Is this Polymorphism metaphor erroneous?

Tags: java, c++, language-agnostic

A metaphor to Polymorphism that is mentioned in C++ from the ground up (by Herbert Schildt) says:

> A simple example of polymorphism is found in the
>   steering wheel of an automobile. The steering wheel (i.e., the interface) is the same no
>   matter what type of actual steering mechanism is used. That is, the steering wheel works
>   the same whether your car has manual steering, power steering, or rack-and-pinion steering. Therefore, once you know how to operate the steering wheel, you can drive
>   any type of car.

I think from some previous readings, that just the **existence** of the steering wheel indicates Polymorphism , not having the *same functionality*. So, In some car, turning the wheel to left could move you to the right.

Which one is more accurate? Or am I confusing it with Duck typing?

Comment: It's more philosophy than programming. Can space shuttle still be called a space shuttle if it is an object designed to take you underwater?

Comment: I wouldnt say that if he didnt explain his point. he says: That is, the steering wheel works the same whether your car has manual steering, power steering, or rack-and-pinion steering

Comment: could you exemplify *In some car, turning the wheel to left could move you to the right.*?

Answer (score 2):

It is not the steering wheel itself that indicates the polymorphism, it is the mechanisms behind the steering wheel that actually performs the steering function that signify polymorphism. The steering wheel along with its expected behavior (clockwise means right etc.) is the metaphor for the `interface`.

The steering wheel stands for the `interface` while the `rack and pinion`, `power` and `manual` are the equivalent of some of the possible `implementation`s.

Comment: Ok, each car then is supposed to have: rack and pinion, power and manual? "That is, the steering wheel works the same"

Comment: @Naughty.Coder - ... **or** ... - it's a strategy pattern.

Comment: he is talking about the fundamentals of OOP.

Answer (score 0):

When you say *steering* wheel, your description literally includes the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

**Polymorphism** means having **many forms**. So in you quote about the polymorphism example about steering wheel the steering wheel has many forms as given in your quote but the usage or the output is the same whatever may be the actual implementation.

Now simple existence of a steering wheel in you example is not polymorphism because, simple existence does not clarify whether this method has different forms or not. It is the actual implementation that determines whether a method is of different types or not or in other words polymorphic or not.